# WCF Server not found error

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, wcf, silverlight-4.0

In a WCF service used by a Silverlight 4 app, I get this error:

> {System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:
>   The remote server returned an error:
>   NotFound. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote
>   server returned an error: NotFound.
>   ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error:
>   NotFound.    at
>   System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at System.Net.Browser
>   ...

It was working at one point, but I made updates and now it's not working.  I can request the service via the URL and it loads the help page and I can examine the WSDL.  FireFox determines that I'm getting a 500 internal service error, so I'm sure that's a factor, but not sure why?

I have the WCF service hosted in cassini for testing purposes.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Do any of your entities have a property with an enum? I've commonly seen this failure when a property is set with a value, say 5, that is undefined in the enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also check if all the classes you use as part of the method arguments carry the [DataContract] and [DataMember] Attributes. If all that seems to be in order, you can try WCF trace to pinpoint the problem.

Turning it on goes like this (web.config):

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
          <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                propagateActivity="true">
          <listeners>
           <add name="traceListener" 
               type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
               initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
          </listeners>
       </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

The resulting file can be double-clicked on and it will be opened in the trace examiner (part of Visual Studio tools). Look for any RED sections, these will lead you to any exceptions occurred in the client-server negotiations.

Hope this helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked all the endpoint settings in the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file?

Answer (score 0):

Check:

1. endpoint address
2. DataContract, DataMember, EnumMember
   atributes of endpoint data contract
3. that you don't transfer int Enum
   value which not exists in Enum
4. if your data contract is inherited
   from some class check KnownType
   attribute
5. if you use service reference sure
   that it's updated